# How to consolidate multiple lists into a single list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

As the products are similar in all 3 functions only the price varies. So is there any way that I can just keep all the products in one function and call them to the other 2 two functions and only change prices in the last two? I don't want to repeat the code for each type

As there are three functions and since it's repeating I want to just keep one main function and then call the product list from the main function to the other two functions except for the price. As the price varies in each. Could someone let me know how to do it? How can I call a function inside another function without having to repeat things?

I want to call the product list from the main function to another two functions so I don't repeat the code and in the two functions I wish to add only prices. How can I do it?

Could someone please let me know what changes I have to make in the code in order to achieve it?

Thanks

```
Product.js

function ProductDataConsolidator() { }

ProductDataConsolidator.get = function () {
    var l = new LawnmowerRepository().getAll();
    var p = new PhoneCaseRepository().getAll();
    var t = new TShirtRepository().getAll();

    var products = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
        products.push({
            id: l[i].id,
            name: l[i].name,
            price: l[i].price.toFixed(2),
            type: "Lawnmower"
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        products.push({
            id: p[i].id,
            name: p[i].name,
            price: p[i].price.toFixed(2),
            type: "Phone Case"
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        products.push({
            id: t[i].id,
            name: t[i].name,
            price: t[i].price.toFixed(2),
            type: "T-Shirt"
        });
    }

    return products;
}

ProductDataConsolidator.getInUSDollars = function () {
    var l = new LawnmowerRepository().getAll();
    var p = new PhoneCaseRepository().getAll();
    var t = new TShirtRepository().getAll();

    var products = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
        products.push({
            id: l[i].id,
            name: l[i].name,
            price: (l[i].price * 0.76).toFixed(2),
            type: "Lawnmower"
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        products.push({
            id: p[i].id,
            name: p[i].name,
            price: (p[i].price * 0.76).toFixed(2),
            type: "Phone Case"
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        products.push({
            id: t[i].id,
            name: t[i].name,
            price: (t[i].price * 0.76).toFixed(2),
            type: "T-Shirt"
        });
    }

    return products;
}

ProductDataConsolidator.getInEuros = function () {
    var l = new LawnmowerRepository().getAll();
    var p = new PhoneCaseRepository().getAll();
    var t = new TShirtRepository().getAll();

    var products = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
        products.push({
            id: l[i].id,
            name: l[i].name,
            price: (l[i].price * 0.67).toFixed(2),
            type: "Lawnmower"
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        products.push({
            id: p[i].id,
            name: p[i].name,
            price: (p[i].price * 0.67).toFixed(2),
            type: "Phone Case"
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        products.push({
            id: t[i].id,
            name: t[i].name,
            price: (t[i].price * 0.67).toFixed(2),
            type: "T-Shirt"
        });
    }

    return products;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? You can call the `.get(currency)` function with a currency argument, so you don't need to keep repeating yourself. Also, you can condense the 3 for loops into an outer for loop. You could also change to using `.map()` but the for loops also work.

```js
//Product.js

function ProductDataConsolidator() { }

ProductDataConsolidator.get = function (currency) {
    var l = new LawnmowerRepository().getAll();
    var p = new PhoneCaseRepository().getAll();
    var t = new TShirtRepository().getAll();
    const arr_names = [
      [l, "lawnmower"],
      [p, "Phone Case"],
      [t, "T-Shirt"],
    ]
    var products = [];
    
    let multiplier = currency == "euro"
                    ? 0.67
                    : currency == "dollar"
                    ? 0.76
                    : 1;
  
    for (let [arr,name] of arr_names){
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        products.push({
            id: arr[i].id,
            name: arr[i].name,
            price: (arr[i].price * multiplier).toFixed(2),
            type: name
        });
      }
    }
    
    return products;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also have dedicated functions for the other 2 currencies that just call the `.get(currency)` with the currency argument included.

```js
//Product.js

function ProductDataConsolidator() { }

ProductDataConsolidator.get = function (currency) {
    var l = new LawnmowerRepository().getAll();
    var p = new PhoneCaseRepository().getAll();
    var t = new TShirtRepository().getAll();
    const arr_names = [
      [l, "lawnmower"],
      [p, "Phone Case"],
      [t, "T-Shirt"],
    ]
    var products = [];
    
    let multiplier = currency == "euro"
                    ? 0.67
                    : currency == "dollar"
                    ? 0.76
                    : 1;
  
    for (let [arr,name] of arr_names){
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        products.push({
            id: arr[i].id,
            name: arr[i].name,
            price: (arr[i].price * multiplier).toFixed(2),
            type: name
        });
      }
    }
    
    return products;
}

ProductDataConsolidator.getInEuros = function(){
  return ProductDataConsolidator.get("euro");
}

ProductDataConsolidator.getInUSDollars = function(){
  return ProductDataConsolidator.get("dollar");
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks its really what i wanted. I tried following the same steps for another js file which is a render page of the above function. But i'm unable to get it. Here's the link to could you suggest for the same please. Thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66474079/how-to-combine-these-functions-without-repeating/66474588#66474588

Answer (score 0):

You first want to use `Array.prototype.map` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on each list to change them to the form you want. For example:

```
const lawnmowers = new LawnmowerRepository().getAll().map((lawnmower) => {
  return {
    id: lawnmower.id,
    name: lawnmower.name,
    price: lawnmower.price.toFixed(2),
    type: 'Lawnmower'
  };
});
```

Then once you have all three lists just concatenate them together with `Array.prototype.concat` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) like so:

```
const products = lawnmowers.concat(phonecases).concat(tshirts);
```

(if you want to go a little more advanced you can use `Object.assign`, or if you have access to it, property spreading syntax to make this even shorter)

### Recommended: Spread Properties

This is not available in Internet Explorer, but otherwise is available in all major web browsers. This would be what I recommend in the majority of cases.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals

```
const lawnmowers = new LawnmowerRepository().getAll().map((lawnmower) => {
  return {
    ...lawnmower,
    price: lawnmower.price.toFixed(2),
    type: 'Lawnmower'
  };
});
```

### Object.assign

In the absence of property spreading, this would be my recommended method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

```
const lawnmowers = new LawnmowerRepository().getAll().map((lawnmower) => {
  return Object.assign(lawnmower, {
    price: lawnmower.price.toFixed(2),
    type: 'Lawnmower'
  });
});
```

Comment: As the products are similar in all 3 functions only the price varies. So is there anyway that i can just keep all the products in one function and call them to other 2 two functions and only change prices in the last two?
I'm afraid if i do it each type as above suggested i will i have to repeat the code again and again which i dont want too.
could please suggest ?