# How to combine these functions without repeating?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

As all the 3 product functions has the same product list how can i combine these multiple functions into one so that i can avoid repeating myself here.

How to combine these three functions into one as all the functions has the product list only the currency are different? Could someone please suggest me. Thanks

```js
function ProductDataRenderer() { }
    
    ProductDataRenderer.prototype.render = function () {
        var nzd = 
            '<table class="table table-striped">'
            +'  <thead>'
            +'      <tr><td colspan="3">Products (NZD)</td></tr>'
            +'      <tr>'
            +'          <td>Name</td>'
            +'          <td>Price</td>'
            +'          <td>Type</td>'
            +'      </tr>'
            +'  </thead>'
            + ' <tbody>';
    
        var n = ProductDataConsolidator.get();
        for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            nzd +=
                '<tr>'
            +       '<td>' + n[i].name +'</td>'
            +       '<td>' + n[i].price + '</td>'
            +       '<td>' + n[i].type + '</td>'
            +   '</tr>';
        }
        nzd += '</tbody></table>';
        document.getElementById("nzdProducts").innerHTML = nzd;
    
        var usd =
            '<table class="table table-striped">'
            + ' <thead>'
            + '     <tr><td colspan="3">Products (USD)</td></tr>'
            + '     <tr>'
            + '         <td>Name</td>'
            + '         <td>Price</td>'
            + '         <td>Type</td>'
            + '     </tr>'
            + ' </thead>'
            + ' <tbody>';
    
        var u = ProductDataConsolidator.getInUSDollars();
        for (var i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
            usd +=
                '<tr>'
            +       '<td>' + u[i].name + '</td>'
            +       '<td>' + u[i].price + '</td>'
            +       '<td>' + u[i].type + '</td>'
            + '</tr>';
        }
        usd += '</tbody></table>';
        document.getElementById("usdProducts").innerHTML = usd;
    
        var euro =
            '<table class="table table-striped">'
            + ' <thead>'
            + '     <tr><td colspan="3">Products (Euro)</td></tr>'
            + '     <tr>'
            + '         <td>Name</td>'
            + '         <td>Price</td>'
            + '         <td>Type</td>'
            + '     </tr>'
            + ' </thead>'
            + ' <tbody>';
    
        var e = ProductDataConsolidator.getInEuros();
        for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            euro +=
                '<tr>'
            +       '<td>' + e[i].name + '</td>'
            +       '<td>' + e[i].price + '</td>'
            +       '<td>' + e[i].type + '</td>'
            + '</tr>';
        }
        euro += '</tbody></table>';
        document.getElementById("euProducts").innerHTML = euro;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey this one should do the trick

```js
const renderTable = ({ items, title, containerId }) => {
  let tableTemplate =
    '<table class="table table-striped">' +
    '  <thead>' +
    `      <tr><td colspan="3">${title}</td></tr>` +
    '      <tr>' +
    '          <td>Name</td>' +
    '          <td>Price</td>' +
    '          <td>Type</td>' +
    '      </tr>' +
    '  </thead>' +
    ' <tbody>'

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    tableTemplate +=
      '<tr>' +
      `<td>${items[i].name}</td>` +
      `<td>${items[i].price}</td>` +
      `<td>${items[i].type}</td>` +
      `</tr>`
  }

  tableTemplate += '</tbody></table>'
  document.getElementById(containerId).innerHTML = tableTemplate
}

renderTable({
  items: ProductDataConsolidator.get(),
  title: 'Products (NZD)',
  containerId: 'nzdProducts'
})
renderTable({
  items: ProductDataConsolidator.getInUSDollars(),
  title: 'Products (USD)',
  containerId: 'usdProducts'
})
renderTable({
  items: ProductDataConsolidator.getInEuros(),
  title: 'Products (Euro)',
  containerId: 'euProducts'
})
```