# How to combine multiple functions into one without repeating?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

In the ProdRender.js I wanna combine those three functions into one so that i do not repeat and that should match to ProdData.js as the data is in the ProdData.js and its rendering through ProdRender.js

Could someone please suggest me how to do it without repeating anything in the prodRender.js The ProdData.js seems to be working fine as i'm not repeating anything only the prodRender.js is where i'm repeating thrice.

So please help me out here

Thanks

```
//ProdRender.js

function ProductDataRenderer() { }

ProductDataRenderer.prototype.render = function () {
    var nzd = 
        '<table class="table table-striped">'
        +'  <thead>'
        +'      <tr><td colspan="3">Products (NZD)</td></tr>'
        +'      <tr>'
        +'          <td>Name</td>'
        +'          <td>Price</td>'
        +'          <td>Type</td>'
        +'      </tr>'
        +'  </thead>'
        + ' <tbody>';

    var n = ProductDataConsolidator.get();
    for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        nzd +=
            '<tr>'
        +       '<td>' + n[i].name +'</td>'
        +       '<td>' + n[i].price + '</td>'
        +       '<td>' + n[i].type + '</td>'
        +   '</tr>';
    }
    nzd += '</tbody></table>';
    document.getElementById("nzdProducts").innerHTML = nzd;

    var usd =
        '<table class="table table-striped">'
        + ' <thead>'
        + '     <tr><td colspan="3">Products (USD)</td></tr>'
        + '     <tr>'
        + '         <td>Name</td>'
        + '         <td>Price</td>'
        + '         <td>Type</td>'
        + '     </tr>'
        + ' </thead>'
        + ' <tbody>';

    var u = ProductDataConsolidator.getInUSDollars();
    for (var i = 0; i < u.length; i++) {
        usd +=
            '<tr>'
        +       '<td>' + u[i].name + '</td>'
        +       '<td>' + u[i].price + '</td>'
        +       '<td>' + u[i].type + '</td>'
        + '</tr>';
    }
    usd += '</tbody></table>';
    document.getElementById("usdProducts").innerHTML = usd;

    var euro =
        '<table class="table table-striped">'
        + ' <thead>'
        + '     <tr><td colspan="3">Products (Euro)</td></tr>'
        + '     <tr>'
        + '         <td>Name</td>'
        + '         <td>Price</td>'
        + '         <td>Type</td>'
        + '     </tr>'
        + ' </thead>'
        + ' <tbody>';

    var e = ProductDataConsolidator.getInEuros();
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        euro +=
            '<tr>'
        +       '<td>' + e[i].name + '</td>'
        +       '<td>' + e[i].price + '</td>'
        +       '<td>' + e[i].type + '</td>'
        + '</tr>';
    }
    euro += '</tbody></table>';
    document.getElementById("euProducts").innerHTML = euro;
}


//ProdData.js

function ProductDataConsolidator() { }

ProductDataConsolidator.get = function (currency) {
    var l = new LawnmowerRepository().getAll();
    var p = new PhoneCaseRepository().getAll();
    var t = new TShirtRepository().getAll();
    const arr_names = [
      [l, "lawnmower"],
      [p, "Phone Case"],
      [t, "T-Shirt"],
    ]
    var products = [];
    
    let multiplier = currency == "euro"
                    ? 0.67
                    : currency == "dollar"
                    ? 0.76
                    : 1;
  
    for (let [arr,name] of arr_names){
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        products.push({
            id: arr[i].id,
            name: arr[i].name,
            price: (arr[i].price * multiplier).toFixed(2),
            type: name
        });
      }
    }
    
    return products;
}

ProductDataConsolidator.getInEuros = function(){
  return ProductDataConsolidator.get("euro");
}

ProductDataConsolidator.getInUSDollars = function(){
  return ProductDataConsolidator.get("dollar");
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: instead of using a lot of `+`, you can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for multi-line strings and variable substitutions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine these functions without repeating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66474079/how-to-combine-these-functions-without-repeating)

Answer (score 1):

You need to break it down to smaller functions and parameterise them

```
const table = (currency, content) =>
    `<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr><td colspan="3">Products (${currency})</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Type</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            ${content}
        </tbody>
    </table>`
;

const table_content = data => 
    data.map(({ name, price, type }) =>
        `<tr>
            <td>${name}</td>
            <td>${price}</td>
            <td>${type}</td>
        </tr>`)
    .join('\n')
;

const currencyCode = {
    dollar: 'USD',
    euro: 'Euro',
    newZealand: 'NZD'
};

function ProductDataRenderer() { }

ProductDataRenderer.prototype.render = function (currency, target) {
    const productData = ProductDataConsolidator.get(currency);
    const html = table(currencyCode[currency], table_content(productData));
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = html;
}
```

I didn't change the design of your code but you can see `render` does 3 different things. It should only render, not also retrieve data and inject the table in the DOM.

It makes also little sense to have one `ProductDataConsolidator` with three static methods having different names. Either you create 3 derivatives of `ProductDataConsolidator` with only one method `get` each and you pass an instance of the right derivative to `render` so that it only needs to know about one method named `get` (by the way if you have one object with only one method it's a function so why bother use an object), or you pass the product data directly to render (preferred)